# Flask App sometimes restarts under mod_wsgi/apache, but not under development server

Tags: flask, psycopg2, mod-wsgi, flask-login

My Flask application runs fine under the Flask development server. After deploying it to apache2 with mod_wsgi it seems to restart after a short time of beeing inactive. That brings problems with loosing the database connection. More detailed:

I use `flask_login` for logging in users. To veryfy the user/password I check them against the PostgreSQL database, making a database connection. If successfull the user will be looged in. The database connection is then used to manipulate the database.

But after a few seconds without activity (even after 10 seconds) the database connection is lost. The entries in my logging files show that my application was restarted. That explains clearly that the database connection is lost.

I use a postgresql database with psycopg2.

The following scripts do not really work. They are meant to illustrate the programming logic I tried. What I have is:

`Model.py`

```py
import psycopg2

class Connections():
    # Holds a postgresql database connection for each user.
    Conns = {}

    create(self, Username, Password):
        # Creates a PostgreSQL database connection and memorizes it for later use
        Conns[Username] = psycopg2.connect(host, Username, Password, ...)

    getConnection(self, Username):
        # Returns the Users database connection
        return Conns[Username]

class Model():
    # Deriving classes describe the underlying database tables.
    # The instances hold a row from the database table.

    # Needs to be initialized manually with
    def Init(Class):
        ...

    # Has for example methods to manipulate the database, as
    def safe(self):
        # INSERT or UPDATE on database
```

`Models.py`

```py
from Model import *

class person(Model):
    _fields = [
        idField('id'),
        textField('name')
        ]

    def __init__(self, id=None, get=False, Username=None):
        # If get=True the instance will be populated with data from database
        # using id
        super().__init(id=id, get=get, Username=Username)
        # The instance must know the username to get the corresponding
        # database connection later.
```

`Application.py`

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, ...
import flask_login

from Models import person

# start the manually initialization
person.Init()

app = Flask(__name__)

login_manager = flask_login.LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

@app.route("/login/")
def login():
    Form = FormLogin() # some LoginForm derived from FlaskForm
    if Form.validate_on_submit():
        Success = Connections.create(Form.user_id.data, Form.password.data)
        if Success:
            user = User(Username) # User class as needed for flask_login
            flask_login(user)
    return some redirect


@app.route("/logout/")
def logout():
    # closes the database connection for the user
```

`wsgi.py`

```py
from Application.py import app

application = app
```

What to do? May be...

- I have to build database connections for each database request. That could be expensive and may slow down the application. (But it works on the development server!)
- Something with my logic for login is basically unusable. (But it works on the development server!)
- `mod_wsgi` must be configured appropriately.
- Something completely different

Any hint? That would be great!

**Edit:**

1. The `apache2` `error.log` doesn't show any entry for my application.
2. A friend told me that `apache2` respectively `mod_wsgi` could stop processes after short time of inactivity to safe recources. In that case it could rather be a problem of my programming logic.
3. A possible solution could be to change the locic.
4. Another possible solution could be to use a lightwight web server instead of `apache2` for my application that leaves it to the programmer to start and stop processes - such as the development server does.

Comment: There should be some output in the Apache error log. See if you can find it and [edit] the relevant parts into the question.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. There isn't any relevant entry in the Apache error log.